# vCard not working on Windows Phone 8

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, vcf-vcard

I have a php script that generates a .vcf file, the file opens on my laptop and I can import as a contact fine. On my windows phone 8 the card downloads but will not open.

My PHP uses the following headers

```
header("Content-type: text/vcard");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

Here is an example of a generated file

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:Joe Bloggs
N:Bloggs;Joe
ADR;WORK:;;test;test;test;
EMAIL:test@test.com
URL;WORK:http://test.com
TEL;type=WORK:123456789
TEL;type=CELL:123456789
REV:2013-07-26T17:59:29Z
END:VCARD
```

Does the format look correct?

Regards

Comment: The format seems good, what error are you getting in your Windows Phone?